# При создании pdf файла через dompdf, в pdf файл не добавляются картинки

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Такая проблема, требуется создать html страницу, отобразить её пользователю, и сохранить её на сервере в виде pdf. Для данной задачи использую dompdf. Текст и таблица отображаются корректно, а вот с картинками возникает проблема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код страницы:

```
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<?php
    ob_start();
?>
<?php 
       $path = 'http://localhost/object_calculator/header.jpg';
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
       ?>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>


</head>
<body>
   <div class="list_1">
      <header>
        <img style="width:100%; height:387px"alt="" src=<?php echo $base64 ?>>
    </header>
    <div class="middle">
      <h1 style="margin-left:4.5%">Коммерческие условия поставки:</h1>
        <br>

  <footer>
    <img src="img/footer.jpg" style="width:90%; margin-left: 4.5%;" alt="">
  </footer>
</div> 
</body>
<?php
  require_once "dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php";
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $my_html =  ob_get_clean();
  echo $my_html;
  $dompdf->load_html($my_html);
  $dompdf->render();
  $output = $dompdf->output();
  file_put_contents("file.pdf", $output);

?>
</html>
```

В чём может быть проблема и как её исправить? Пытался использовать base64, и путь полный прописывал

Comment: Не понятно, откуда Вы получаете `$type`. + к тому в тег `a` Вы добавляете `a.appendChild(table);` хотя `table` - это не один, а несколько элементов. Так как Вы используете `getElementsByClassName`, что подразумевает получение нескольких элементов.

Comment: @Denis640Kb, причём тут таблица, если она нормально отображается? вопрос задан про картинки

Comment: А вам уже написали. Переменная `$type` не определена. Переменная `$base64` нигде не используется

Comment: давайте вы приведете минимальный воспроизводимый пример, а не вот это все. если таблица выводит корректно, то не надо нам и код с ней скидывать. Начните с того, что у вам src надо в кавычки заключить. В случае генерации pdf следует абсолютный путь указать, а в случае вывода а браузер - относительный. Возможно, это будет работать с одним и тем же путем, если картинка лежит в директории где и файл. и да. пишите про base64, но нигде это не используете.

Comment: @ArchDemon, переменная base64 использовалась, в данном примере она не используется

Comment: @ArchDemon, внёс правку в код вопроса, теперь используется $type и $base64, но результат не поменялся

Comment: @teran, внёс правку, ничего не изменилось, но при этом в браузере всё нормально выводит

Comment: Да что же вы так невнимательно. `src="..."` кавычки забыли. Перед записью в pdf неплохо бы убедиться, что `$type` и `$base` содержат необходимые значения.  `ob_get_clean();` нужно делать раньше, require_once может вам подгадить вывод.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153139/dompdf-remote-image-is-not-displaying-in-pdf вот есть несколько советов. Или сделайте pdf на примере из этого вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пришлось скачать более раннюю версию dompdf 0.8.0

```
<?php
      $image = 'header.jpg';
      $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
      $src = 'data:'.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;
      $my_html =  '
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>

        <style>
          html, body{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
          }
          body{
            background:#3d3d3d;
          }
          .list_1{
            width:70%;
            margin-left: 15%;
            margin-top:2%;
            background:white;
          }
          .tab{
            margin-top: 1%;
            margin-left: 4.6%;
            width:90%;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bolder;
          }
          td{
            padding:20px
          }
          tr{

          }
          body { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
       <div class="list_1">
          <header>
            <img style="width:100%; height:387px"alt="" src="' .$src. '">
        </header>
        <div class="middle">
          <h1 style="margin-left:4.5%">Коммерческие условия поставки:</h1>
            <br>
            <table class="summa tab" border="1">
              <tr>
                <th>Наименование продукции</th>
                <th>Сумма с НДС, руб</th>
                <th>Количество</th>
                <th>Сумма с НДС, руб</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Понтон модульный</td>
                <td id="col_p">16800</td>
                <td id="shet_p">'. $_GET["shetpon"] .'</td>
                <td id="shet_sum_p">0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Соеденитель понтона</td>
                <td id="col_s">280</td>
                <td id="shet_s">'.  $_GET["connector"].'</td>
                <td id="shet_sum_s">0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Лестница с соеденителем</td>
                <td id="col_st">18560</td>
                <td id="shet_st">'.$_GET["stairs"] .'</td>
                <td id="shet_sum_st">0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Сходня с переходником</td>
                <td id="col_g">9400</td>
                <td id="shet_g">'.$_GET["gangway"] .'</td>
                <td id="shet_sum_g">0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Лавочка с соеденителями</td>
                <td id="col_sit">12500</td>
                <td id="shet_sit">'.$_GET["bench"].'</td>
                <td id="shet_sum_sit">0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Утка</td>
                <td id="col_u">20</td>
                <td id="shet_u">'.$_GET["duck"] .'</td>
                <td id="shet_sum_u">0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Стойка</td>
                <td id="col_stay">890</td>
                <td id="shet_stay">'.$_GET["stays"].'</td>
                <td id="shet_sum_stay">0</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>ИТОГО</td>
                <td></td>
                <td id="final_col">0</td>
                <td id="final_sum">'. $_GET["sum"].'</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
      <footer>
        <img src="img/footer.jpg" style="width:90%; margin-left: 4.5%;" alt="">
      </footer>
    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function load(){
        document.getElementById("shet_sum_p").innerHTML= document.getElementById("shet_p").innerHTML * document.getElementById("col_p").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("shet_sum_s").innerHTML= document.getElementById("shet_s").innerHTML * document.getElementById("col_s").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("shet_sum_st").innerHTML= document.getElementById("shet_st").innerHTML * document.getElementById("col_st").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("shet_sum_g").innerHTML= document.getElementById("shet_g").innerHTML * document.getElementById("col_g").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("shet_sum_sit").innerHTML= document.getElementById("shet_sit").innerHTML * document.getElementById("col_sit").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("shet_sum_u").innerHTML= document.getElementById("shet_u").innerHTML * document.getElementById("col_u").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("shet_sum_stay").innerHTML= document.getElementById("shet_stay").innerHTML * document.getElementById("col_stay").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("final_col").innerHTML= +document.getElementById("shet_p").innerHTML + +document.getElementById("shet_s").innerHTML + +document.getElementById("shet_st").innerHTML +  +document.getElementById("shet_g").innerHTML + +document.getElementById("shet_sit").innerHTML + +document.getElementById("shet_u").innerHTML + +document.getElementById("shet_stay").innerHTML;
       }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
      ';
      header('Content-language:en-GB');
      require_once "\dompdf\autoload.inc.php";
      use Dompdf\Dompdf;
      $dompdf = new Dompdf(array('enable_remote' => true));
      $dompdf->load_html($my_html);
      $dompdf->setPaper( 'A4', 'portrait' );
      $dompdf->render();
      //$output = $dompdf->output();
      //file_put_contents("file.pdf", $output);
      $dompdf->stream();
      echo $my_html;
    ?>
```